# Subset dataframe based on other dataframe in R to create symmectical matrices for Mantel Test

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-science, subset

I am new to R and in need of advice how to subset a dataframe based on another dataframes data, so that they match, looking at number of rows and columns. 
My overall goal is to perform a Mantel test between different versions of a test suite.
To do so, I have to compare the subset of the test cases that exist in Version 1 and Version 2, since in Version 2 more test cases have been added, but for a Mantel test you need (preferably) two symmetrical Matrices. 
How my matrices look (small examples, they can have up to 4 million fields):

```
File | testA | testB | testC | ...
testA|  0.0  | 0.62  |  0.45 | ...
testB|  0.62 | 0.0   |  0.12 | ...
testC|  0.45 | 0.12  |  0    | ...
```

What I am doing so far:

```
matrixA<- read.csv("data\\distanceMatricesJacksonDatabindV112\\dm_jaccard.csv", header = FALSE)
matrixB<- read.csv("data\\distanceMatricesJacksonDatabindV112\\dm_NCD.csv", header = FALSE)
testMantel = mantel(matrixA, matrixB, method = "spearman", permutations = 99, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This code reads in my distance matrices (csv format) as dataframes and then performs a Mantel Test on them. It currently does not include headers as headers, since then the comparison does not work. However they are available and used as headers when I chose "TRUE", as you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

This only works, as long as the amount of rows and columns is identical between the dataframes. Therefore I am looking for a way to assure that only entries (identified by the first column and row) that are present in MatrixA will be extracted from MatrixB to MatrixC and then compared to MatrixA, to look for generational changes. 
So this is how I would need it to look:

```
Matrix A                 Matrix B                         Result: Matrix C
File | testA | testB |   File | testA | testB | testC |   File | testA | testB |
testA|  0.0  | 0.643 |   testA|  0.0  | 0.3   |  0.64 |   testA|  0.0  | 0.3   |
testB| 0.643 | 0.0   |   testB|  0.3  | 0.0   |  0.2  |   testB|  0.3  | 0.0   | 
                         testC|  0.64 | 0.2   |  0.0  |
```

As visible in the example, testB must have changed between Matrix A and Matrix B, since the value changed from 0.643 to 0.3. TestC should not be present in Matrix C, since it is not known to Matrix A. Also important: The new tests are not added in the bottom automatically. They can be anywhere in the matrix, between the old cases.
I have tried this (and many more) but I receive an error message saying "non-square matrix"

```
required_df <- jaccardV2[jaccardV2$V1 %in% jaccard$V1,]
```

I would be really grateful for any help

Update: I have found a solution and added it in the last post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question, which I will lay out in the code snippet bellow. Thank you @dcarlson for the help, it got me much closer to my final solution.
To extract the subset of the 2 matrices that is present in both I have come up with this function.

```
get_version_subset <- function(v1_matrix, v2_matrix){
rownames(v1_matrix) <- v1_matrix[,1]
v1_matrix <- v1_matrix[,-1]
rownames(v2_matrix) <- v2_matrix[,1]
v2_matrix <- v2_matrix[,-1]
subsetList <- intersect(colnames(v1_matrix), colnames(v2_matrix))
return(subsetList)
}
```

For the next step I installed the library tidyverse. I am filtering for "File", since my first column has this name.

```
subsetList <- get_version_subset(matrix1, matrix2)
subset <- matrix2%>%filter(File %in% matrix1$File) %>% select(1, subsetList)
```

Lastly you need to adjust the new matrix "subset" to assure that the labels are set correctly, which I have done in this function:

```
adjust_first_column <- function(matrix) {
rownames(matrix) <- matrix[,1]
adjustedMatrix <- matrix[,-1]
return(adjustedMatrix)
}
```

Hope that this will help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to compare two symmetrical matrices (distance or correlation) and extract the rows/columns that are found in both. First we need some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(rnorm(36, 36, 6), 6, 6)
colnames(x) <- paste0("test", LETTERS[1:6])
MatA <- x[, sort(sample(1:6, 4))]
MatB <- x[, sort(sample(1:6, 4))]
(MatA.cor <- cor(MatA))
#            testA      testB     testE      testF
#  testA 1.0000000  0.1978459 0.5318998  0.1388820
#  testB 0.1978459  1.0000000 0.3979890 -0.1806799
#  testE 0.5318998  0.3979890 1.0000000  0.4346770
#  testF 0.1388820 -0.1806799 0.4346770  1.0000000
(MatB.cor <- cor(MatB))
#            testA      testC      testE     testF
#  testA 1.0000000  0.0552819  0.5318998 0.1388820
#  testC 0.0552819  1.0000000 -0.3562452 0.5533406
#  testE 0.5318998 -0.3562452  1.0000000 0.4346770
#  testF 0.1388820  0.5533406  0.4346770 1.0000000
```

Since we used one matrix to create MatA and MatB, the correlations are the same. In your actual data they will different. MatA includes tests A, B, E, and F while MatB includes tests A, C, E, and F. We want to create matrices with the same tests:

```
both <- intersect(colnames(MatA.cor), colnames(MatB.cor))
both
#  [1] "testA" "testE" "testF"
```

Tests A, E, and F are common to both matrices so those are the ones we extract:

```
MatA.cor[both, both]
#            testA     testE    testF
#  testA 1.0000000 0.5318998 0.138882
#  testE 0.5318998 1.0000000 0.434677
#  testF 0.1388820 0.4346770 1.000000
MatB.cor[both, both]
#            testA     testE    testF
#  testA 1.0000000 0.5318998 0.138882
#  testE 0.5318998 1.0000000 0.434677
#  testF 0.1388820 0.4346770 1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I feel like this goes in the right direction, but R studio tells me "error in cor(jaccard): 'x' has to be numeric".I wonder if I am doing something wrong while importing?

Comment: I should have used MatA.cor and MatB.cor in creating both and in extracting the rows/columns. I've made those corrections. You are not using a correlation matrix so you should use the names of your distance matrices: both <- intersect(colnames(MatrixA), colnames(MatrixB)), and then MatrixA[both, both] and MatrixB[both, both]

Comment: Ok, I have updated my description with the implementation according to your suggestion, something is still not working the way it should. I have notices something though. When I chose "Headers = TRUE" in the csv reading, it will tell me that there are 73 obs. of 74 variables. When I turn the headers of, correlation does not work, since it just puts V1,V2,V3 etc. in the first column, but it say 74 obs. of 74 variables. Could this be important?
Really grateful that you are helping!

Comment: You should use "headers=TRUE` (note the capitalization, R is case sensitive). Your first column is the test ID so you appear to have a distance matrix of 73x73. But you keep changing the names of your matrices. Is it MatrixA or jaccard? Also is the first column `File` as in your picture? It appears that you need to convert the first column to row names to have a valid distance matrix, e.g. rownames(MatrixA) <- MatrixA[, 1] and then MatrixA <- MatrixA[, -1]. Print out a piece of MatrixA after this, print(MatrixA[1:10, 1:10] to make sure it is formatted as a distance matrix.

Comment: Try readLines("data\\distanceMatricesJacksonDatabindV112\\dm_jaccard.csv", 5) and post what that produces so we can see what the file looks like. It may not be a proper .csv file.

Comment: Ok, so I have used the commands to convert the first row, and now it is a symmetric matrix! That is already awesome. When I look at the outcome after the conversion the  "File" in the first column has disappeared but now the file says it has 73 obs. of 73 variables. It does look like a valid distance matrix if I open the variable in the environment by double click. When I use the print command, it prints column after column, showing the distances between the headline test and all the others.
I am sorry for the confusion, I changed the matrix name during the process for better readability.

Comment: I have updated my post accordingly, adding the output of the readLines command. I have also tried to run the commands from yesterday after i converted the matrices and added the output as a screenshot, as well as the file how it looks after the conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231042/discussion-between-mocde-and-dcarlson).